# Why is Routes.rb not loading the IPs from cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached

I am testing this in local. My ip is `127.0.0.1`. The ip_permissions table, is empty. When I browse the site, everything works as expected.

Now, I want to simulate browsing the site with a banned IP. So I add the IP into the ip_permissions table via:

```
IpPermission.create!(:ip => '127.0.0.1', :note => 'foobar', :category => 'blacklist')
```

In Rails console, I clear the cache via; `Rails.cache.clear`. I browse the site. I don't get sent to `pages#blacklist`.

If I restart the server. And browse the site, then I get sent to `pages#blacklist`. Why do I need to restart the server every time the ip_permissions table is updated? Shouldn't it fetch it based on cache?

Routes look like:

```
class BlacklistConstraint
  def initialize
    @blacklist = IpPermission.blacklist
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @blacklist.map { |b| b.ip }.include? request.remote_ip
  end
end

Foobar::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/(*path)' => 'pages#blacklist', :constraints => BlacklistConstraint.new
  ....
end
```

My model looks like:

```
class IpPermission < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :ip, :note, :category
  validates_uniqueness_of :ip, :scope => [:category]
  validates :category, :inclusion => { :in => ['whitelist', 'blacklist'] }

  def self.whitelist
    Rails.cache.fetch('whitelist', :expires_in => 1.month) { self.where(:category => 'whitelist').all }
  end

  def self.blacklist
    Rails.cache.fetch('blacklist', :expires_in => 1.month) { self.where(:category => 'blacklist').all }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing BlacklistConstraint in your routes file which is loaded only once at the start. There you call IpPermission.blacklist and store it in an instance variable. Initialize is not called anymore and therefore you check against the same records.

You should load the records on each request if you want them to be updated:

```
class BlacklistConstraint
  def blacklist
    IpPermission.blacklist
  end

  def matches?(request)
    blacklist.map { |b| b.ip }.include? request.remote_ip
  end
end
```